# Nlog json cofiguration problem Required parameter 'WrappedTarget' on 'AsyncWrapper Target[xxx]()' was not specified

Tags: json, nlog

```
 <target name="asyncAsb" xsi:type="AsyncWrapper">
            <target
                name="asb"
                type="AzureServiceBus"
                connectionString="xxx"
                queue="logs_queue" />
        </target>
```

trying to setup through json like this

```
"asyncAsb": {
                    "type": "AsyncWrapper",

                    "targets": {
                        "asb": {
                            "type": "AzureServiceBus",
                            "connectionString": "xxx",
                            "queue": "monitor_queue"
                        }
                    }
                },
```

but got error 
**"Required parameter 'WrappedTarget' on 'AsyncWrapper TargetasyncAsb' was not specified."**

Does anybody have example of this section ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose we are talking about https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Extensions.Logging project which allows to configure NLog using JSON appsettings.json configuration file.

From their samples https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Extensions.Logging/blob/master/examples/NetCore2/ConsoleExampleJsonConfig/appsettings.json we can see the following syntax for your case:

```
"targets": {
  "asyncAsb": {
    "type": "AsyncWrapper",
    "target": {
      "asb": {
        "type": "AzureServiceBus",
        "connectionString": "xxx",
        "queue": "monitor_queue"
      }
  }
}
}
```

Comment: The link above no longer works but here it is from a past commit: https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Extensions.Logging/blob/407e66fd2b8c3f19c75e20fc9f66f15032ad861f/examples/NetCore2/ConsoleExample/appsettings.json